# What's -mutableSetValueForKey: returning, actually? Is that something special?

Tags: iphone, core-data

From the docs:

> You usually access to-many
>   relationships using
>   mutableSetValueForKey:, which returns
>   a proxy object that both mutates the
>   relationship and sends appropriate
>   key-value observing notifications for
>   you.

So this returns an "intelligent" NSMutableSet which automatically lets the context delete objects when they get deleted from the set, and reverse? Is that a proxy object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. See [Accessor Search Pattern for Unordered Collections](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/SearchImplementation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000955-SW3) in the Key-Value programming guide for details.

Comment: Wow, that method is actually really intelligent. Impressive! (Yes, I really did quit my day job to have more time learning all this stuff)